# PostgreSQL won't run after upgrading to High Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I upgraded my Mac to High Sierra.
I use PostgreSQL for Rails.

This is what happens when I try to start PostgreSQL:

```
Davids-iMac:~ davidburton$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

Comment: The var folder looks empty.

Comment: make the folder and chown it to the postgresql user... or chmod it 777 for testing.

Comment: Thanks - make your comments into an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if I can improve the answer in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the "/usr/local/var/postgres/" folder either does not exist or has the wrong permissions.

In terminal you can do the following:

```
 sudo chown postgres /usr/local/var/postgres/
```

Note: the "postgres" above will need to match whatever username postgres postmaster is using to run.

or

```
 sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/var/postgres/
```

Comment: I get `chown: postgres: illegal user name` I have used this user in the past, but now it seems to be unavailable upon update

Comment: I have a user on my mac called _postgres -- perhaps that's what's necessary instead of "postgres" -- you can look at the /etc/passwd file in terminal to find your list of users that are available to "chown" things to.